# What about "Did you know?" or "tip" posts/questions?

Tags: discussion

I know about some nice (quite hidden) features of WP7 that I found on the net (and I am sure others have too). I want to share them with users of this SE site, but how can I do that?

- Making up a question just to have a place to share the "tip" in answer seems wrong to me.
- Also I think marking Q or A as community wiki is not right.

What are other options?

Comment: A blog, but it might be too early for that. Other than that, there's our chat. Can't think of any other solutions that might/would work well...

Answer (score 2):

If you have found something that solves a specific problem, there is no reason why you shouldn't share it here. Just ask the question in a meaningful way, and then provide an answer so fantastic that it becomes **the** source of record.

The StackExcahnge network has no problem with this, and I don't think we should either. Just read the latest blog post yourself. [Encyclopedia StackExchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) **(emphasis mine)**

> Since Stack Overflow launched, we’ve been trying to explain that
>   **it’s not just a Q&A platform: it’s also a place where you can publish things that you’ve learned**: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs,
>   walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, **as long you
>   format it as a question and answer**...
>
> For a long time we’ve been pleading for people to write more canonical
>   answers so the same questions don’t keep coming up again and again,
>   and we even have the Self-Learner badge which you can only earn by
>   answering your own question...

IMHO, just don't make a question like "What tips have you learned?" If you have a couple of tips you want to share because it solves an awesome problem on the phone, just keep it Q/A style.

Comment: One of the tip I want to share is "When you are typing text, tap the space bar twice and WP7 makes a full stop for you (it will end the sentence with a dot)". What question should look like for this? I don't like "How can I make a full stop?" or "What will happen when I tap space bar twice?"... Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that one by itself is a bit too localized ,and wouldn't be a great question. Can you expand it to something like "are there any keyboard shortcuts that can help me type faster" and then include as many as you know/can find in the answer. I'm just.spit baling here, but something like that could be useful

Comment: Yes, that is probably the right formulation. Thanks. I will try to formulate it myself to fit the answer.

Comment: Ok, posted here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/509/what-keyboard-shortcuts-can-i-use-when-typing-on-wp7/510#510

Comment: The blog post you linked is meant to [support asking/answering your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Questions like the OP asked [are usually not constructive](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and [aren't meant to be community wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) either. While this questions contain somewhat very valuable stuff, "Did you know ...?" and "Can you share tips on ...?" questions don't usually work well.

Comment: Trying to change tips into questions that are **about a problem**, that's a *hard* thing.

Comment: @TomWijsman I agree, that is why I stated `ask the question in a meaningful way, and then provide an answer so fantastic that it becomes the source of record` If he has a tip that actually solved a problem he had there is no reason why he can't ask/answer himself. The example I gave in my comment was off the top of my head at midnight :) The purpose was to make him think about a broader problem, not a specific double tap.

Comment: @Joe: I agree. Also, your edit is what makes the difference regarding constructiveness...

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use a question transformed into a community wiki like this :[What factors should I consider when choosing a Windows Phone device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-factors-should-i-consider-when-choosing-a-windows-phone-device)

I think @tom-wijsman made that an wiki. I like the way that questions and answer is.

Comment: Do you mean one question for tips? Something like "What tips do you know?".

Comment: Please read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/ and furthermore note that I only put my answer that way and the question is intact. To summarize that blog post: Community Wiki is not the solution for stuff that doesn't fit on your community...

Comment: @TomWijsman I undestood your point of view.